# SQL Join Statement

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a simple mysql query which is as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(node.nid) AS nid,
node_counter.totalcount AS node_counter_totalcount,
node.title AS node_title,
node_data_field_dep.field_dep_value AS node_data_field_dep_field_dep_value,
node.type AS node_type,
node.vid AS node_vid,
node_data_field_type.field_type_value AS node_data_field_type_field_type_value
FROM node node 
LEFT JOIN node_counter node_counter ON node.nid = node_counter.nid
LEFT JOIN content_field_dep node_data_field_dep ON node.vid = node_data_field_dep.vid
LEFT JOIN content_type_project node_data_field_type ON node.vid = node_data_field_type.vid
WHERE (node.type in ('project')) AND (node.status <> 0)
GROUP BY nid
ORDER BY node_counter_totalcount DESC
```

so i execute the following statements:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

where $query is the above SQL query.

Usually, I use mysql_fetch_array($result) or mysql_fetch_row($result) to access the data, but these are not working now and instead giving some error. Is there any other way to use them. I want to print the data selected in a formatted manner.(Say, a table)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /var/www/test/index.php on line 26

Comment: use  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); to get error message;

Comment: So, what does `mysql_error()` return? Because it seems that the query is not executing properly. You won't get your data any other way than by `mysql_fetch*`.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. There was a small problem in my query!!! :( I was aware of die method but don't use it... Now, will remember to use the 'die' method so that the errors can be tracked properly. :D

Comment: You should use the die-statement with the error message only in developing-environment. In production systems it's not very good to populate such sensitive information about a failed query and the database, since "evil people" could try something stupid, with the information :).

Answer (score 0):

It means your query is not executed, there is some error in it or maybe in the connection. 
You can find out what the error is using mysql_error() like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($myquery) or die(mysql_error());
```

or you can use

```
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo($row);
```

If it returns 1 or higher it means your query is returning results.